# Passing Javascript variable to PHP page with url

Tags: javascript, php

I have a javascript function that loads a PHP page and passes a variable(testvar) to it

```
function selectcity()
{

      var testvar = "test text";
     $("#list").load("selectcity.php?testvar");
     $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

}
```

Now in the selectcity.php page,I am trying to retrieve the variable like this :
But not working,Can someone pls help.

```
<?php
echo $_GET['testvar'];
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't set the value, only the variable name in the URL.

Change to:

```
$("#list").load("selectcity.php?testvar=" + encodeURIComponent(testvar));
```

Comment: Only 2 people answering actually read the question fully - congratulations on being one of them ;)

Comment: @MrCode. Is there any way to pass multiple variables instead of just one ?

Comment: @user3541562 you can add more using the format `testvar=a&second=b&third=c`, or pass an object like `$(..).load('myurl', { testvar : 'a', second : 'b', third : 'c' })`

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
$("#list").load("selectcity.php", {
    testvar: testvar
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set a value there as well...

```
$("#list").load("selectcity.php?testvar=true");
```

right now "testvar" is empty, so echoing it will echo an empty string... hard to see an empty string that way...

If you want the string 'testvar' to show in the URL use this:

```
$("#list").load("selectcity.php?testvar="+testvar);
```

You can also pass parameters like this:

```
$("#list").load("selectcity.php",{
   testvar: testvar,
   moreparam1: "some value",
   evenmore: 124
});
```

Comment: its working..but is there any way to pass multiple variables ??

Comment: see answer, extended on the original answer a bit

Answer (score 0):

Because you set the variable "testvar" but do not put any thing in it.

```
$("#list").load("selectcity.php?testvar=foobar");
```

Should work.